# Flex-wrap with rows of different heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am implementing css-only tabs with hash-tag linking. I'm very very close but can't quite get the flex wrapping to work properly. In order for everything to work they way I want it to with `:target` (I've done this before with radio buttons and that gives a bit more flexibility), I need all tabs and all sections at the same level so I have:

```
body
  section
  anchor
  section
  anchor
  ...
```

I can then use flexbox ordering to make all anchors appear first and style the appropriately, set all sections to width 100% and use `flex-wrap` to allow them to wrap to the next line. The problem is that I seem to be unable to control the height of the first row. What's going on here?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
body > a {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  order: -1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  border: solid gray;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
}
body > a:last-of-type {
  order: -2;
}
section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
section:last-of-type {
  display: flex;
}
a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
a:last-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
}
:target {
  display: flex;
}
:target ~ section {
  display: none;
}
:target ~ a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
:target + a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="advanced">
 Advanced Stuff
</section>
<a href="#advanced">Advanced</a>

<section id="home">
 Home Things
</section>
<a href="#home">Home</a>
```

[Slightly easier to play with jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kufele/edit?html,css,output)

The issue is that the tabs in the first row stretch to the height of the visible section rather than collapsing to the height of their contents. Even a specific `height` and `max-height` seems to be ignored.

Please note, the question is specifically about line heights when wrapping with flexbox. I know a million different ways to build tabs both in css and js. I'm specifically looking for a deeper understanding of `flex-wrap`.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to happen when the tabs wrap? Maybe you could illustrate your desired outcome.

Comment: @Michael_B run the example - you see how they're stretching to be the same height as the section rather than collapsing to the size of their contents? I want them to look like tabs but instead they're all stretched out. I want both rows to size to their contents

Comment: Two initial settings of a flex container are `align-items: stretch` and `align-content: stretch`. You can override this by changing the value to `flex-start`.

Comment: @Michael_B `align-content` seems to get me very close but that for some reason makes the `section` no longer fill down vertically.

Comment: So you want `stretch` on wide screens and `flex-start` on narrow screens?

Comment: @Michael_B no, I just want the visible section to flex and occupy all available space which it doesn't if you give the container `align-content: flex-start`. [See this example](http://jsbin.com/kufele/5/edit?html,css,output) note how the section with the tan background doesn't stretch to the bottom, even though the flex container *does* and the section has `flex-grow: 1`. Honestly, I"m not sure I understand why `align-content` would do that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two initial settings of a flex container are `align-items: stretch` and `align-content: stretch`. You can override this by changing the value to `flex-start`.

But that seems to solve only part of the problem. You also want selected wrapping items to stretch the full height of the container.

This isn't happening because *when flex items wrap they take only the minimum size necessary to contain their content.*

From the flexbox spec:

> [**6. Flex Lines**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-lines)
>
> In a multi-line flex container (even one with only a single line), the
>   cross size of each line is the minimum size necessary to contain the
>   flex items on the line (after alignment due to `align-self`), and the
>   lines are aligned within the flex container with the `align-content`
>   property.

In other words, when there are multiple lines in a row-based flex container, the vertical height of each line (the *"cross size"*) is the *"minimum size necessary to contain the flex items on the line"*.

To make your layout work you would need a combination of row- and column-direction flex containers, along with an adjustment to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `height: 100vh` from `body` and `flex-grow: 1;` from `section`

What happens is you set the body to be full height and then tell the section to grow full available space, hence they fill the browser height.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
body > a {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  order: -1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  border: solid gray;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
}
body > a:last-of-type {
  order: -2;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
section:last-of-type {
  display: flex;
}
a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
a:last-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
}
:target {
  display: flex;
}
:target ~ section {
  display: none;
}
:target ~ a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
:target + a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="advanced">
 Advanced Stuff
</section>
<a href="#advanced">Advanced</a>

<section id="home">
 Home Things
</section>
<a href="#home">Home</a>
```

Sample 2, using a wrapper

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  height: 100vh;
}
body > div {
  flex: 0;
  order: 1;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  order: 2;
}
body > div > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: solid gray;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
}
section:last-of-type {
  display: flex;
}
a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
a:first-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
}
:target {
  display: flex;
}
:target ~ section {
  display: none;
}
:target ~ div a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
#home:target ~ div a[href='#home'],
#advanced:target ~ div a[href='#advanced'] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="advanced">
 Advanced Stuff
</section>

<section id="home">
 Home Things
</section>

<div>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#advanced">Advanced</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well...yes, but removing `height: 100vh` fundamentally changes what it does. The section will no longer expand to the bottom. In practice that would probably be a `min-height` btw.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Ok, so when you said _I want both rows to size to their contents_, what does that actually mean? ... that the `section` should always fill the remaining space left by the `tabs`?

Comment: exactly. The section should fill space vertically (it has `flex-grow: 1`) and the tabs should collapse to their contents

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Updated with a 2:nd suggestion, using a wrapper, as the wanted behavior is not going to be achieved with the existing markup/css

Comment: I appreciate this and it helps a lot. Going to accept Michael's answer as it helps explain a bit better to me whats going on and taught me something about `flex-wrap` but thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I only see a solution if the height of the tabs is known using `calc` to calculate the height of the section:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

body > a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  order: -1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  border: solid gray;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

body > a:last-of-type {
  order: -2;
}

section {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  height: calc(100% - 32px)
}

section:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}

a {
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:last-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
}

:target {
  display: block;
}

:target ~ section {
  display: none;
}

:target ~ a {
  font-weight: normal;
}

:target + a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="advanced">
  Advanced Stuff
</section>
<a href="#advanced">Advanced</a>

<section id="home">
  Home Things
</section>
<a href="#home">Home</a>
```

Comment: If you're doing that, you don't need to `calc`. Remove the `align-content` rule and set all `body>a` to have `height: 32px`. Not a bad solution actually...